# i want to store the button in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a nine button using for loop, i want to store the button in an array because i want to access all button at a time.

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
    num1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [num1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [num1 setTag:tag_start+i];
    num1.tag = currentTag;
    currentTag++;
    [num1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentTag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [num1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [num1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [num1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:35.0]];

    //Store the button in array
    [numBtnArray addObject:num1];

    NSLog(@"%d", numBtnArray.count);    //it show 0 nothing in that array

    if(i >= 5) {
        num1.frame = CGRectMake(430, i*60-160, 50, 50);
    }
    else {
        num1.frame = CGRectMake(350, i*60+140, 50, 50);
    }
    [num1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [num1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [num1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:num1];
}
```

Comment: access all button at a time ?? what is this mean ??

Comment: You are apparently already adding the buttons to an array (numBtnArray). What is your question exactly?

Comment: i.e., if i change color for all nine button in single line of code using array

Comment: Have you initialised your array?

Comment: yes i initialized my array but i check that array using NSLog it shows 0

Comment: Initialise it numBtnArray = [NSArray new];

Comment: Where are you creating your array? Could you show us a bit more of your code perhaps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is the requirement but if you need to store them in an array simply do

```
NSMutableArray *btnArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {
        // ...
        [btnArray addOjnect:num1];
        [self.view addSubview:num1];
    }
```

Comment: NSArray *btnArray = [NSArray new]; is added in first line

Comment: You are adding twice . and also it doesn't make sense

Comment: It needs to be a mutable array.

Comment: there is no meaning to adding in array at same time adding sub view.

Comment: Since num1 is not local variable all the objects in that array will be same (the last created button)

Comment: @Vaisakh Not if the variable is reassigned a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as follows

```
numBtnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {

        UIButton *num1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //...

        //Store the button in array
        [numBtnArray addObject:num1];

        NSLog(@"%d", numBtnArray.count);    

        //...
 }
```

Comment: 'addObject' possible for NSMutableArray only and num1 should be local variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but I would encourage you not to store the buttons in an array at all, as the `UIView` already does that.

If you want to perform some sort of *mass change* to the buttons then you can, either:

1. Set a tag value in the button, so you can identify them later (with a minimum or maximum range).
2. Only target the buttons by testing their class.

So, if you want to change the background colour of the buttons in `self.view`, you simply:

```
for (id obj in self.view.subviews) {
    if (![obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        continue;
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)obj;
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it could be that he is adding other types of buttons elsewhere, I definitely say there are cases where holding those in an array might help readability...

Comment: @nickfalk I think the fact that there are two references to each button, which must be managed (think about what happens if a button is removed), negates readability.

Comment: Not saying it's the default way to go, but it's a pattern fairly common in sprite-based games for instance to have sprites to be removed added to an array to be emptied at the next view cycle for instance.

Comment: @nickfalk Sure, but the OP's *use case* was "mass change".